# Why does axios throw an error with npm run prod, but not npm run dev/watch?

Tags: javascript, npm, import, axios

I have a Laravel project using Vue.js and Axios with Laravel Mix to build CSS/JS assets.

While developing, I've been using `npm run dev` and `npm run watch` to build assets without issue. I tried using `npm run prod` once to check bundle sizes, but as soon as I did that, even though everything compiles without issues, all Axios requests in the web app start throwing errors.

Specifically, I noticed the following:

If I import Axios directly from `node_modules` as follows:

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

Then Axios requests work fine, even when using `npm run prod`.
However, I created my own Axios library that I'd prefer to use because it has header presets, etc. I can import the Axios library I built as follows:

```
import axios from './lib/axios';
```

If I do that in combination with `npm run prod` and then attempt something like a standard `axios.get()` call that works fine with `npm run dev/watch`, then I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

What's interesting is that even if I literally only do the following in `lib/axios.js`, I still get the same error on `npm run prod` builds:

```
import axios from 'axios';
export default axios;
```

Why would simply importing and exporting Axios from a file and then importing Axios from that file (`lib/axios.js`) cause errors on prod builds only, but importing Axios directly from `node_modules` not cause errors? I'm so confused. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Does changing the name of your own library works or have you tried changing the name to other rather than `axios`?

Comment: Cedric, thanks for your help. I was continuing to search around before you responded, and I came across this semi-related page: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1092. One guy suggested using the `version()` method in the `webpack.mix.js` file to fix that problem, so I figured I'd try the same for mine. I did that and it magically just worked. Zero clue why! All I can say is that if you add `version()` to the end of the chained methods on the `mix` object, it works. No issues with `npm run prod` or `npm run dev`. Thanks for your help. It got me thinking more.

Comment: As another note, I tried removing `version()` and rebuilding to see what would happen with `npm run prod`. It still works fine! Maybe it was just some weird caching issue all along? I legitimately don't know, but all the same, it's working. Thanks.